# Azure CLI key vault recovery showing error messages - does it have a retry strategy?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I have an Azure CLI script for copying secrets from a reference key vault to another key vault. As this script will be run multiple times it checks whether each key has been soft-deleted, and if so this version will be recovered.

The newly-recovered key's value is then checked to determine whether it needs updated.

```
write-host Recovering a soft-deleted secret for $secretName
az keyvault secret recover --name "$secretName" --vault-name $keyVaultName

if ((az keyvault secret show --name "$secretName" --vault-name $keyVaultName --output json | convertfrom-json | select-object value).value -eq "$secretValue"){
    write-host The recovered secret has the correct value for $secretName
}
```

A problem arises when the first instruction has recovered a secret and the second instruction asks for this secret (to compare its value):

> ResourceNotFoundError: (SecretNotFound) A secret with (name/id) [...] was not found in this key vault. If you recently deleted this secret you may be able to recover it using the correct recovery command. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125182

This sometimes appears multiple times.

However, this is then followed by...

> The recovered secret has the correct value for [...]

...which gives me the impression that the `show` command has some sort of built-in retry strategy, though I can't find any documentation of this.

I've also tried placing the `show` command inside a try/catch but no error is ever caught.

I want the script to run without any errors - can anyone tell me how to properly handle this recover-then-retrieve process without incurring any errors, even if the script somehow moves on and eventually checks the value successfully?

---

**Update:**

I was able to work around this problem by capturing the secret from the `recover` command...

```
$recoveredSecret = (az keyvault secret recover --name "$secretName" --vault-name $keyVaultName --output json --only-show-errors | convertfrom-json | select-object value)

if ($recoveredSecret.value -eq $secretValue){
    write-host The recovered secret has the correct value for $secretName
}
```

But I'd still like to know why the `show` command fails and then appears to retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure CLI key vault recovery showing error messages - does it have a retry strategy?

I could reproduce this issue on my side.

**That because recover command need takes a certain amount of time to recover the secret.**

After sending the recover command, Powershell will execute the next command without waiting for the recover command to complete. However, the background needs some time to execute the recover command. But if we use the show command immediately after the recovery command, we will encounter this error, because the background recover operation may not be completed.

That is the reason why this issue sometimes appears multiple times.

To resolve this issue, we just need add a sleep command after recovery command:

```
az keyvault secret recover --name "$secretName" --vault-name "$keyVaultName"

Start-sleep -Seconds 30

if ((az keyvault secret show --name "$secretName" --vault-name "$keyVaultName" --output json | convertfrom-json | select-object value).value -eq "$secretValue"){
    write-host The recovered secret has the correct value for $secretName
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that certainly answers the question.  
For what it's worth, I'd prefer an API where the operations were deterministic - if an instruction has returned then I expect that it's job is done. There are some operations in the Azure CLI which have a `--no-wait` argument - that's great because then I know that I've asked it to return while the operation is still in progress. But the key vault operations _don't_ have this so it's implied that the request has been fulfilled when the operation returns, and it turns out that this is not true.